# Env variables on Solaris

Tags: solaris

How do i display all the env variables and value of a particular env variable on a solaris server?

Answer (score 4):

Open up a shell and type `env`. This will show you all environment variables in the current shell.

Use the name of a specific variable, prefix it with a `$` and do `echo $name` to echo the value of the env variable **name**.

Answer (score 1):

You can view all environment variables using a shell with

```
set | more
```

Comment: csh does not show all environment variables using set

Answer (score 1):

The way to display environment variables doesn't depends that much one the operating system, as far as Unix and Unix like systems are concerned.

If you want to know the exported variables, i.e. those that are inherited by subprocesses, you can use the `export` shell builtin/alias or the `env` command. Otherwise, `set` is the usual way to display all shell environment variables.

As already answered, for any specific variable, use `echo $variable`